# Plot function in octave converting single value to matrix

Tags: matlab, octave

I am new to octave. I want to plot lh value for each theta. I am calculating that lh value using below function.

```
function lh = compute_lh (D, theta)
lh = 1
  for i=D
   if i == 1
      lh = lh * theta
    else
      lh = lh * (1-theta)
    endif
  end
endfunction
```

D = =[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
where theta is generated with theta = 0:0.01:1

plot(theta,compute_lh(D,theta))

error: compute_lh: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x101, op2 is 1x101)
error: called from compute_lh at line 29 column 10
error: evaluating argument list element number 2

I don't know why that theta is converted to matrix while plotting.

Comment: Surely something like `lh=theta.^sum(D==1).*(1-theta).^(sum(D~=1))` is easier than this? Even `lh=theta.^nnz(D).*(1-theta).^nnz(~D)` if `D` only has 1's or 0's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` operator is *matrix multiplication*.

Your error occurs because at line `lh = lh * theta`, the first time this is called, you're "matrix multiplying" a scalar with a horizontal matrix, resulting in a horizontal matrix. The second time, you're trying to "matrix multiply" a horizontal matrix with another horizontal matrix, and that is not a mathematically correct operation, so you get an error.

Presumably you need the `.*` operator, which is "element-wise" multiplication.
Change to that, and you'll see the bell curve result you want.

Comment: @AnipPatel no, when you call `f(x)`, for a vector `x`, the entire vector is passed in to the function.